# .gitattributes linguist-language declaration

Tags: git, repository, gitattributes

I am currently working on a little python package, and the whole source is in my git repo. I have seen around that github doesn't track cython files in the repo statistics correctly. So i have just created a `.gitattributes` file, of which I found the documentation [here](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes). At the end my file looks something like this:

```
# Specify Python source files. 
*.py linguist-language=python
*.pyi linguist-language=python

# Highlight Cython source files as C language, since it's hopefully better
# than nothing. This also affects repo statistics.
*.pyx linguist-language=C
*.pxd linguist-language=C

# Specify python binary files.
*.db binary
...

# Jupyter notebook
*.ipynb text

# Highlight C and C++ source files.
*.c linguist-language=c
*.cc linguist-language=cpp
*.cxx linguist-language=cpp
...

# Compiled Object files
*.slo binary
...

# Compiled Dynamic libraries
*.so binary
...
```

Is declaring all that bunch of extensions a common practice to do?
And is `*.pyx linguist-language=C` something that can be done without giving the nearest python developer a heart attack?

Comment: Git itself pays no attention to linguist-language: that's more a GitHub feature. "Best practice" is not really a StackOverflow thing though. Consider, e.g., softwareengineering.stackoverflow.com instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that Cython should be recognized by [linguist](https://github.com/github/linguist/blob/master/lib/linguist/languages.yml#L1110-L1116), the library used on GitHub.com to detect blob languages.

```yaml
Cython:
  type: programming
  group: Python
  extensions:
  - ".pyx"
  - ".pxd"
  - ".pxi"
```

A project like [`Calamitizer/rainbow-of-code`](https://github.com/Calamitizer/rainbow-of-code) does illustrate that, and do use a [`.gitattributes` with](https://github.com/Calamitizer/rainbow-of-code/blob/0dca53f55ebce9db4a25874e7da485b7daeb171a/.gitattributes#L82):

```
*.pyx linguist-language=Cython
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering my question. Does making all that declarations something useful to do (e.g. `*.py linguist-language=python`)? I have seen that [numpy](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/main/.gitattributes) for example doesn't do that

Comment: For *.my itself, I suspect you don't have to do that.